# I'm trying to replace a tag with database value using template_replace_values in tinymce (personalizer)

Tags: tinymce

any example for template_replace_values(functions) in TinyMCE.

So that we can change something like %%username%% to "John K"

We will store the templates in mysql which include tags (%%username%%) and when execute TinyMCE the tag will be replaced with original values from database.

(Trying to send personalized mails)

Thanks in advance

Comment: str_replace("%username%",$username,$filebody).  Working